# Dex error after opening project on a different computer

Tags: android, android-studio, dex

I have copyied my android-studio project to another computer and installed a fresh copy of android-studio. Then I opend my project and when trying to run got this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --force-jumbo --output D:\tfs\TicRetail\Android-androidStudio\app1\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\ksoap2-android-assembly-3.3.0-jar-with-dependencies-529bf9ff78c48d88b8ff9d314fce08b41c252434.jar D:\tfs\TicRetail\Android-androidStudio\app1\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\app1\pj1\unspecified\libs\ksoap2-android-assembly-3.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Error Code:
    255
Output:
    The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have tried cleaning project and rebuilding but it doesen't seem to work.

Any ideas what the cause would be?

Comment: Your ksoap2-android-assembly-3.3.0-jar reference not founded.

Comment: My  ksoap2-android-assembly-3.3.0-jar is in the same directory as before in libs there should not be a problem there :/

Comment: I tried deleting nad reinstalling (sdk included) no difference and I cannot open sdk manager either.